# Como puedo buscar un dato en un arreglo en c#

Tags: c#, array

la verdad estoy empezando soy nuevo en la programacion estoy realizando un proyecto para una materia de mi carrera en este proyecto debo crear un programa que me permita guardar curps los datos de la persona la curp, edad, nombre, sexo y este programa debe ser capas de realizar la busqueda mediante la curp aparte de que debe mostrar el total de registros, por genero y en general mi pregunta es cual es el metodo que puedo utilizar para hacer la busqueda mediante la curp y cual otro puedo utilizar para mostrar el registro por genero y en genral que existen en el arreglo y digo arreglo porque es por el cual se ingresan los datos de la curp, edad, genero, nombre

este es el arreglo que logre programar

```
        int i = 0, aux = 0;
        string Respuesta;
        string[] CURP = new string[10];
        string[] Nombre_Completo = new string[10];
        float[] Edad = new float[10];
        string[] Genero_de_Persona = new string[10];
        Console.WriteLine("Ordenador de CURP");

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Escriba su CRUP por favor");
            CURP[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Escriba su Nombre Completo por favor");
            Nombre_Completo[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Escriba su Edad por favor");
            Edad[i] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Escriba su Genero por favor");
            Genero_de_Persona[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("¿Capturar otro registro?");
            i++;
            Respuesta = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        while (Respuesta.ToUpper()=="SI" && (i<5));
        Console.WriteLine("Arreglo lleno");
         
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            aux=j+1;
            Console.WriteLine(" La CURP es: "+CURP[j]+ " El nombre en la posición "
                              +aux.ToString()+" es : "+ Nombre_Completo[j]
                              +" con una edad de: "+ Edad[j]+ " y su genero es: "+Genero_de_Persona[j].ToString());
        }
        
        Console.Write("Presione una tecla para continuar ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Comment: Que es curp?....

Comment: son letras y numeros

Comment: Porque no haces una clase Persona que tenga los datos que deseas, y haces un arreglo de tipo Persona, no 4 arreglos

Comment: El curp es la identificación legal de una persona en México, como el NIF en España

Answer (score 0):

Como eres nuevo en esto no te voy a molestar con lo que se podría mejorar de tu código. Aunque deberías hacer caso a @Japv. A parte de más legible, despues te servirá para almacenar los datos, etc.

Una función de búsqueda sería algo así (revisa porque la hice de memoria):

```
 public int Buscar (string[] almacenados, string curpBusqueda)
    {
        if (almacenados == null || almacenados.Length == 0) return -1;
        if (curpBusqueda == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("curpBusqueda");
        }

        bool encontrado = false;
        int posicion = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < almacenados.Length && !encontrado; i++)
        {
            if (string.Compare( almacenados[i], curpBusqueda, true) == 0)
            {
                encontrado = true;
                posicion = i;
            }
        }

        return posicion;
    }
```

Aunque con Linq puedes hacerla más sencilla dependiendo de si quieres la posición u otras cosas. Si añades el using, hay cosas como búsquedas, etc. que se quedan en 1 línea de código.

```
using System.Linq;

public bool EstaRegistrado(string[] almacenados, string curpBusqueda)
    {
        if (almacenados == null || almacenados.Length == 0) return false;
        if (curpBusqueda == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("curpBusqueda");
        }

        return almacenados.Contains(curpBusqueda);
    }
```